# Accessing server at a certain time

Tags: ios, time, server, alarm

I am trying to create an app where at a certain time the user sets (like an alarm) the app access the server, gets the data, and sends the alarm to the user if requirement is satisfied.

Is there any way to achieve this feat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You can't do that. iOS doesn't let you run your app as a daemon like that, or wake up at specific times. The best you could do is to create scheduled local notifications that display a message to the user asking them to tap to open your app, which would then connect to the server.

Comment: what if the app is in the background? or if the phone is turned off would the app not be able to perform any task?

Comment: No. The only way this is possible is if the app is running in the foreground or background at the time you want to connect. (And you only get 3 minutes of background time before you get suspended - excluding turn-by-turn navigation apps and music streaming apps, which need to register for continuous background execution.)

Comment: ok.. so achieve this I need to create a remote push server where I push the users from the server.. Thank you. Is it the same for androids? or can I loop through a different method in android?

Comment: Android OS doesn't have the same limitations. You can run a Daemon or a chron job on Android.